# Error: 'demo.table_name' doesn't exist

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1146

I am trying to create a procedure in MySql as following

```
delimiter //
 create procedure search11(in table_name char(10))
 begin
 select * from table_name;

 end; //
```

But when I am calling it as
CALL search11('account');

It gives this error

ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'demo.table_name' doesn't exist

what's wrong with this....??

Comment: the use of database object as tablename or column name is not allowed  as variable  .. in sql

Comment: `execute("SELECT * FROM "  table_name)` or  `execute(concat('SELECT * FROM ',table_name))` dynamic SQL would be needed; though this opens the door to SQL injection. so ensure the table_name values are sanitized!  and Dynamic SQL suffers from the fact it can not be precompile for performance benefits.

Comment: these two commands are leading to errors...but